# Why does adding a negative risk premium to the short rate avoid the occurrence of inverse yield curves?

Tags: yield-curve, factor-models, short-rate, vasicek, numeraire

I am reading about the Vasicek One Factor short rate model and how to implement a change in measure from a risk-neutral to real-world measure, when I came across this comment:

> Adding a negative risk premium to the short rate will in principle
> avoid the occurrence of inverse yield curves.

Why would this be the case? What could be a possible intuitive interpretation or justification for this statement?

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Long rates can be decomposed into expected short rates and a term premium (constant with Vasicek). The yield curve slope is low when short rates are expected to decline. But when term premium is sufficiently large the slope is still positive.

Comment: Because the Term Premium is (usually) assumed to add to interest rates an amount proportional to the Maturity T (i.e. it is linear in maturity), it has a bigger effect at longer maturities. Thus contributing to creating a rising term structure.